# How to find character locations of a string in a file?

Tags: grep, string, search, character-encoding

I need to search for a string (a sequence of characters) in a file with a certain encoding, typically utf8, but return the character offsets (not byte offsets) of the results.

So this is a search that should be *independent* of the encoding of the string/file.

`grep` apparently cannot do this, so which tool should I use?

Example (correct):

```
$ export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" 
$ echo 'aöæaæaæa' | tool -utf8 'æa'
2
4
6
```

Example (wrong):

```
$ export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
$ echo 'aöæaæaæa' | tool 'æa'
3
6
9
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your input and show how you would  like to get the output as?

Comment: added minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current versions of Perl, you can use the `@-` and `@+` magic arrays to get the positions of the matches of the whole regex and any possible capture groups. The zeroth element of both arrays holds the indexes related to the whole substring, so `$-[0]` is the one you are interested in.

As a one-liner:

```
$ echo 'aöæaæaæa' | perl -CSDLA -ne 'BEGIN { $pattern = shift }; printf "%d\n", $-[0] while $_ =~ m/$pattern/g;'  æa
2
4
6
```

Or a full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Encode;
use open  ":encoding(utf8)";
undef $/;
my $pattern = decode_utf8(shift);
binmode STDIN, ":utf8";
while (<STDIN>) {
    printf "%d\n", $-[0] while $_ =~ m/$pattern/g;
}
```

e.g.

```
$ echo 'aöæaæaæa' | perl match.pl æa -
2
4
6
```

(The latter script only works for stdin. I seem to trouble forcing Perl to treat all files as UTF-8.)

Comment: this gives the byte positions, not the character positions.  how can I get the character positions for utf8 text as in the example? nice code though!

Comment: @user239558, right you are. I seem to have some trouble getting Perl to treat everything as utf-8, but there's a script or two that seem to work now.

Comment: Maybe `PATTERN=æ perl -Mopen=locale -MEncode::Locale=env -l -0777 -ne 'BEGIN{$pattern = env("PATTERN")} print $-[0] while /\Q$pattern\E/g' <<< 'aöæaæaæa'` for the decoding to be based on the locale's encoding.

Comment: The updated one-liner looks very good!

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#m) which in patterns causes the matched portion to be
                    # made available in $MATCH and the offset (1-based) in $MBEGIN
                    # (and causes the expansion of the replacement in
                    # ${var//pattern/replacement} to be deferred to the
                    # time of replacement)

haystack=aöæaæaæa
needle=æ

offsets=() i=0
: ${haystack//(#m)$needle/$((offsets[++i] = MBEGIN - 1))}
print -l $offsets
```

Comment: nice one! I'm not used to `zsh` being a contender here.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` or any other POSIX compliant `awk` implementation (not `mawk`), and correct locale set:

```awk
$ LANG='en_US.UTF-8' gawk -v pat='æa' -- '
{
    s = $0;
    pos = 0;
    while (match(s, pat)) {
        pos += RSTART-1;
        print "file", FILENAME ": line", FNR, "position", pos, "matched", substr(s, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        pos += RLENGTH;
        s = substr(s, RSTART+RLENGTH);
    }
}
' <<<'aöæaæaæa'
file -: line 1 position 2 matched æa
file -: line 1 position 4 matched æa
file -: line 1 position 6 matched æa
$
```

The pattern indicated in the `-v pat` argument to `gawk` can be any valid regular expression.